# Sugestions needed for Joomla control panel

Tags: php, web-applications, joomla

I would like your suggestions on how to proceed in making a control panel in PHP to manage different resources: it needs to let the user edit remote .xml, .php .js and Joomla's pages in a user-friendly manner. The user would not have access to the code, but only to images or text that they could change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create three systems.

- To handle the page creation, deletion and template designs (closed to the end-user?)
- To add, edit and remove resources like images, videos, texts, et cetera.
- To make associations, like "I want this, this and that listed on that page".

The final engine should iterate through the associations, find the proper resources, and display them correctly using a template.